# Using variable names in prepared statements via ODBC API

Tags: c++, odbc, prepared-statement

I have a C++ project that still uses concatenated SQL statements instead of prepared statements. The project makes use of the plain ODBC API without any third party library as far as I can see.

Now I have to switch this project to prepared statements.

From Delphi using Unified Interbase (UIB) I'm used to write something like

```
Query.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES (:id, :name);'
Query.Params.ByNameAsInteger['id'] := 42;
Query.Params.ByNameAsString['name'] := 'Panic';
...
```

There also seems to be a similar name binding in Qt even when using an ODBC data source (at least according to the tutorial I've just found).

According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms716365%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it looks like I have to use SQLPrepare using just quotation marks as place holders and SQLBindParameter. For SQLBindParameter I have to specify way more information than I have to when using UIB or qt

```
// excerpt from MSDN example
SQLPrepare(hstmt, "UPDATE Parts SET Price = ? WHERE PartID = ?", SQL_NTS);
SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_FLOAT, SQL_REAL, 7, 0,
                 &Price, 0, &PriceInd);
```

Am I just missing a part or is this that "complicated" when using plain ODBC API?

Comment: Well, it looks like [google tiodbc](https://code.google.com/p/tiodbc/wiki/CommunityExamples) makes this a bit easier and better readable.